# Do we know if this is really Queen Esther's Village?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

While I was driving today ([at this location](https://plus.google.com/100859857675571297494/about?gl=us&hl=en)), I was surprised to happen upon:

[image: Queen Esther's Village]

Is there any evidence in the *megillah* or any other part of our *mesorah* that this is indeed the village that Queen Esther came from?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Pretty funny :-) !

Answer (score 5):

This is a suburb of Clevland, Ohio, known as "the mistake on the lake". Although the apparent reason for that appellation is related to financial difficulties and poorly performing sports teams, the Kabbalistic reason is because its traditions are unreliable. This is an example of the latter.

Answer (score 5):

Shh!

לא הגידה אסתר את מולדתה

This question, as well as whatever marking were photographed here, should be taken down immediately!!! I can't even imagine what horrible things might occur if someone found out.... you have no right to be הולך רכיל ומגלה [הסתר] אסתר

Comment: she may not have told anyone, but the google maps car found out all her personal info

Answer (score 3):

This **should** have been Queen Esther's village.

If you recall, on several occasions Ahashverosh is willing to offer Esther up to half of his kingdom. At no point does Esther take up the offer. Ahashverosh, however, is nice enough to name the village after his Queen, hoping that she may someday change her mind and decide to live in Ohio. So, until that happens, he has to rent the place, as you can see by the sign.